# How to keep Django sessions active when using jQuery Ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a Django application that has a few pages. If a user clicks through the app, the session expires after 30 minutes (configured with `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1800`). But if the user stays on the page and reloads data via jQuery AJAX requests, the session lifetime does not extend and expires.

How can I accomplish that the session also extends when using Ajax requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` setting that saves sessions and sends the session cookie with every request.

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax request to extend your session like this

```
def update_session(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() or not request.method=='POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])

    request.session['mykey'] = 'myvalue'
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

You JavaScript will be like this

```
$.post('/update_session/', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```